# How to deploy for ECS with new instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I use ECS with EC2 instances (not Fargate), but finding the best way of deployment.
To be immutable infrastructure, I want to deploy new task definitions (Docker images) for ECS and run new EC2 instance has it. But famous deployment libraries, [amazon-ecs-cli](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli) and [ecs-formation](https://github.com/openfresh/ecs-formation) and [ecs-deploy](https://github.com/silinternational/ecs-deploy), [hako](https://github.com/eagletmt/hako), are not meeting these requirements. These seem to be able to deploy a new task definition for a current instance.

Is there a deployment tool meeting these requirements?

Comment: we are using ecs-deploy. It meets all our requirements